# Getting illegal character range in regex :java

Tags: java, regex, escaping, string-matching

I have a simple regex pattern that verifies names. But When I run it I get illegal character range error. I thought by escaping "\s" it will allow a space but the compiler is still complaining.

```
public boolean verifyName(String name) {
    String namePattern = "^[\\p{L}]++(?:[',-\\s][\\p{L}]++)*+\\.?$";
    return name.matches(namePattern);
}
```

and this is the error that i think shouldn't be occurring since a name might contain anny of these `[',-\\s]`

so where am i not understanding?

Comment: why are you using `++` instead of `+`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't have a range "from `,` to whitespace". Perhaps you meant to escape `-`?

`\s` is not a space, it's `[ \t\r\n\v\f]` (space, tab, carriage return, newline, vertical tab or a form feed).

Things that will work:

```
"[ ',-]"

"[',\\- ]"
```

Comment: so how should the range be...I want only to allow an apostrophe, hyphen, comma or space

Comment: If you want a space, use a space. If you put the hyphen last, you don't need to escape it: `[ ',-]`